# Hibernate FetchMode.SUBSELECT is ignored with Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have an entity tree consisting of a parent with a many to many relationship with a child entity as described below (in kotlin). Why is hibernate seemingly ignoring the FetchMode we associate with the entity relation?

**Observed behaviour:**
When executing a findAll on the JpaRepository of the parent, the FetchMode.SUBSELECT is ignored and hibernate fires off a new select for each Parent to fetch the children.

**Expected behaviour:**
When executing a findAll on the JpaRepository of the parent, hibernate fires off a single select with a subselect to fetch the children for all the parents.

**Tech:**
Spring boot 2.4.2 with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
class Parent (
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "parent",
        sequenceName = "parent_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 50
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parent_generator")
    val id: Long? = null

    @Fetch(SUBSELECT)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "parent_child",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "child_id")]
    )
    val children: MutableList<Child>
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
class Parent (
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "parent",
        sequenceName = "parent_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 50
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parent_generator")
    val id: Long? = null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe Hibernate just can't use SUBSELECT fetching because you are modelling a bag. Does it work if you use a `Set` instead of a `MutableList`?